# HTML Box alignment

Tags: html, css

So, whenever there is content inside the boxes, they align weird and not side by side. How do i fix this? Ive tried quite alot and i havent been able to figure it out.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated/

So i have This as my main code:

```css
.content-wrapper {
     background-color: #B31CFF;
     width: 100%;
     height: 1000px;
    }

    .content {
     background-color: #E3E3E3;
     width: 80%;
     height: 1000px;
     margin-left: 10%;
     margin-right: 10%;
    }
    
    
    .donator-box {
     border: 3px solid #FFF;
     background-color: #FFF;
     margin: 1%;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 47%;
     height: 250px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .donator-box {
     padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
   
 <div class="content">

  <div class="donator-box">
   <div class="donator-content">
    content
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="donator-box">
   <div class="donator-content">
    content
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="advert">

  </div>
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  box-sizing: border-box; at ".donator-box"

```css
 .content-wrapper {
background-color: #B31CFF;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
}

.content {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    width: 80%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}


.donator-box {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 47%;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.donator-box {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="content-wrapper">

        <div class="content">

                <div class="donator-box">
                    <div class="donator-content">
                        content
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="donator-box">
                    <div class="donator-content">
                        content
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="advert">

                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much:)

Comment: @ColinCappetto thnx, make it please as a correct answer :)